# How do you upload a file (from url) to a Docker container?

Tags: rest, docker, copy, dockerfile, pocketmine

How would somebody use the Docker Engine API to stop a container, upload a file (from a url) to a path in a container, then run the start command again? I am running [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nathjeid/pocketmine-mp/). The intention is to have a Minecraft Server then upload a plugin from a url and restart it. I have seen the `docker cp` command although it is best to be able to do it from the RESTful API.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy files to a running container using `docker cp`, but I think what you really want to do is build a new image based on that other image.

Dockerfile

```
FROM nathjeid/pocketmine-mp:latest
ADD ./FileToCopy.txt /FolderToCopyTo
```

Then run `docker build -t mycoolimage .`

Result: You now have a docker image called "mycoolimage" that is identical to nathjeid/pocketmine-mp, plus the file you want to add.

If you want to get the file from a url rather than from your local file system you can use the RUN command in your Dockerfile and use `curl`. If the image doesn't already have `curl` on it you'll need to install it.

[Docker cp docs page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

[Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

[Docker build docs page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a running container use docker cp. A shell script like this should work:

```
wget http://example.com/file.out
docker cp file.out yourcontainer:/desired/path/file.out
docker restart yourcontainer
```

Alternatively you can use another container (named, for example, *administrator*) and share a volume with your plugins. The other container can be a restful server (ex. python flask or whatever) that uploads file to the shared volume.

If you want to start, restart the first container from the *administrator* container you must run the *administrator* container sharing the docker sock like this:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

More explanations for docker restart from another container:

[Is it possible to start a stopped container from another container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468841/is-it-possible-to-start-a-stopped-container-from-another-container)

Answer (score 0):

The `<src>` in the `ADD` instruction can be a remote file URL:

E.g.:

`ADD https://www.example.com/hello.txt /tmp/`

will download the file under /tmp