# Node.js child_process.exec "/bin/sh: 1: docker: not found" error

Tags: node.js, docker, microservices, moleculer

I created a micro-service using the "Moleculer" framework. I used child_process.exec for running docker commands in a shell. I get "**/bin/sh: 1: docker: not found**" error.

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
.
.
.
exec("docker --version", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   if (error) {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
      return;
   }
   console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
   console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
   });
```

Tried giving absolute path as:

```
exec("/usr/bin/docker --version", (err...);
```

But still got the same error.

I am able to get the node version using:

```
exec("node --version", (err...);
```

Comment: Docker is installed on your machine and does same cmd is working from cmd line? Just want to be sure before thinking anything else.

Comment: Is it alpine based image, alpine does not has sh or bash in the image.

Comment: @RohitJindal yes, docker is installed on my machine and commands work fine in the terminal.

Comment: @AakashSharma I am getting an error from /bin/sh that docker is not found. So, sh must exist in the image I am using.

Comment: The micro-service from which I use child_process to run shell/docker commands is running inside a docker container (In that container, docker wouldn't be installed). So I think it won't have access to the docker installed on my machine from within that docker container. I was confused because for some reason I was able to run "ls" command to see directory contents at the path where docker is installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. The reason was simply that I had built a new image but the Docker client was not present in my container because I only did `docker-compose restart <CONTAINER_NAME>` and not `docker-compose stop <CONTAINER_NAME>`, `docker-compose rm <CONTAINER_NAME>` and `docker-compose up -d <CONTAINER_NAME>`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63281470/1707015