# Run new docker container (service) from another container on some command

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Does exist any way to do this:

- run one service (container) with main application - server (flask application);
- server allows to run another services, them are also flask applications;
- **but I want to run each new service in separate container** ?

For example, I have endpoint `/services/{id}/run` at the server, each **id** is some service id. Docker image is the same for all services, each service is running on separate port.

I would like something like this:

request to server - `<host>//services/<id>/run` -> application at server make some magic command/send message to somewhere -> service with id  starts in new container.

---

I know that at least locally I can use docker-in-docker or simply mount docker socket in container and work with docker inside this container. But I would like to find way to work across multiple machines (each service can run on another machine).

For Kubernetes: I know how create and run pods and deployments, but I can't find how to run  new container on command from another container. Can I somehow communicate with k8s from container to run new container?

---

Generally:

- can I run new container from another **without docker-in-docker and mounting docker socket**;
- can I do it with/without Kubernetes?.

---

Thanks for advance.

Comment: This isn't a best practice.  In Kubernetes it's a little less risky than in plain Docker (look up how to call the Kubernetes API) but it's complicated to manage and easily opens you up to denial-of-service attacks.  Better is to use a job queue like RabbitMQ and a worker that can be managed by a Deployment object.

Comment: I understand that it isn't the best practice. So I would like to know what is. How can I initiate running of new docker container from another container? My question not only about Kubernetes, but can I solve this problem using any tool(s).

Comment: As previous community member said. This is not a best practice. I would suggest looking at this links: 1.[StackOverflow control docker from container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468841/is-it-possible-to-start-a-stopped-container-from-another-container/39469893#394698930 2. [Exposing dockerd api](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-enable-the-remote-api-for-dockerd)  3.[Docker engine security](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/). Is there any particular reason that you need to start containers this way?

Comment: @DawidKruk Thank you for links. 
Particular example: machine learning deployment. Services: frontend, backend. Frontend = UI where I can select model from list and click button "Deploy" (calls some backend endpoint). Then backend runs new model server in separate container.

Comment: @AlexKolosov are these deployments which will calculate something will be created by you? Most important do you intend to give access to other people to run it?

Comment: @DawidKruk Both in production and dev the goal - collaborative work: anyone, who has access, can press button "Deploy" on UI at server (or call endpoint). As result - new container with model will run.
In dev I would like to do without k8s. But 
the principle is the same: do some command inside one container -> run new container.
I would like just to know all ways to run new docker container from another, with and without k8s. Except using docker-in-docker and docker-out-of-docker. If they are exist, of course - I couldn't find:( If no - than no, I want just to know. Thanks.

Comment: I would encourage you to look at this 2 links: 1.[Kubernetes access API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/) 2.[Kubeflow](https://www.kubeflow.org/)

Comment: @DawidKruk Thank you for your answers! I worked with Kubeflow, now I'll dig around in Kubernetes API/

Comment: @AlexKolosov I answered your question with all the links that we talked about. If this helped you please upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've compiled all of the links that were in the comments under the question. I would advise taking a look into them:

Docker:

- [StackOverflow control Docker from another container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468841/is-it-possible-to-start-a-stopped-container-from-another-container/39469893#394698930). 
  The link explaining the security considerations is not working but I've managed to get it with the Webarchive: [Don't expose the Docker socket (not even to a container)](http://web.archive.org/web/20190623234615/https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container.html)
- [Exposing dockerd API](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-enable-the-remote-api-for-dockerd)
- [Docker Engine Security](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/)

Kubernetes:

- [Access Clusters Using the Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/)
- [Kubeflow](https://www.kubeflow.org/) in the spite of machine learning deployments